# WPF underline binding (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Is there a way to bind underline?? I'm trying to achieve the following: 
I have `VievModel` with a bool property: 
 `public bool HomeButtonUnderline { get; set; } = false;`
I would then like to control this property in the following function:

```
public void Home() {
//CurrentPage = ApplicationPage.Home;
//HomeButtonForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
HomeButtonUnderline = true;
SettingsButtonUnderline = false;
}
```

I could then utilize this control in XAML:

```
<Button>
<TextBlock Command="{Binding HomeNavCommand}" Underline="{Binding HomeButtonUnderline}"/> 
</Button>
```

The problem is that there isn't an 'Underline' property, instead it is handled by 'TextDecorations':

```
<Button>
<TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline">
</Button>
```

So is there a way to control underline using MVVM or even without it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Converter to convert your model types (in this case, a bool) to the UI types (in this case, a TextDecoration).

```
public class UnderlineConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value) ? TextDecorations.Underline : null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And then use it in your binding (after creating a resource in your Window, UserControl App.xaml or whereever you feel is the right place; for this sample I'm just putting it in the button resources)

```
<Button Command="{Binding HomeNavCommand}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <local:UnderlineConverter x:Key="UnderlineConverter" />
    </Button.Resources>
    <TextBlock TextDecorations="{Binding HomeButtonUnderline, Converter={StaticResource UnderlineConverter}"/> 
</Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use a DataTrigger in a Style for the TextBlock:

```
<Button Command="{Binding HomeNavCommand}">
    <TextBlock Text="Home">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HomeButtonUnderline}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Solution works, but I prefer the value converter for a bit cleaner code.

Comment: @Yoghurt -- Actually you are slightly backwards :). DataTriggers are the way to go. This is just a one time thing. What are you going to do when you need to set 20 properties on an object? Create 20 custom converters? Heck no!

Comment: @SledgeHammer - but what if you want to bind the underline property for 20 different text blocks, each to different properties? Then you'd need 20 DataTriggers, or a single converter. Both methods are useful in the right situation - it's "horses for courses".

Comment: @SledgeHammer now that I finally have enough reputation to comment: I wouldn't create 20 converters. I would try to make a generic enough converter (like BoolToValueConverter) and just create that one in XAML with the values I need (in this case, TextDecorations.Underline for true and null for false). This doesn't always work, but quite often it does. What I like about converters vs. DataTriggers is that converters do not clutter the XAML as much (that's subjective, I know). If I need to set 20 properties in response to 1 property in the ViewModel I would definetely use a DataTrigger though.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, another way to handle this is for your view model to be the right type for the view:

```
public TextDecorationCollection HomeButtonUnderline { get; set; }
```

`HomeButtonUnderline` is already GUI-orientated, so there's probably some code in your viewmodel that assigns a value from the model, so it might as well also convert from `bool` to `TextDecorations.Underline`.

This method keeps all the logic in the same file, unlike a converter, although a converter is more reusable. It also has the advantage of being easily unit-testable (unlike a data trigger).

Comment: I like this solution, because often adding few lines of code in C# lead to a much cleaner and better understandable solution than trying to do it in XAML.